# Titanium: How to close TabGroup within its Tab?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

How can I close the **TabGroup** within one of its **tab** ?

I want to close the tabGroup on a button click (Log out button) and want to display a window without the tab group. I know how to display a window but could find how to close tab group ?

I think, to hide tab group is not proper way. Also on another button (Login button) I am creating the tab group so...

Any suggestions ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just do this:

```
TabGroup.close();
```

Put your tabgroup name instead of TabGroup.

**EDIT:**

If you want to access your tab grop through out the app do this in your app.js file:

```
Ti.App.customTabGroup = customTabGroup;
```

and close the tabgroup like this:

```
Ti.App.customTabGroup.close();
```

Comment: "Can't find variable: TabGroup"; I got this

Comment: What is the name of your tabgroup?

Comment: see, I have created tab group in app.js named customTabGroup

Comment: Oh, can you access customTabGroup in that button event, if you can then do `customTabGroup.close();`

Comment: Great.. :) Team India up voting Team Pakistan.. :P